# Distributing FFMPEG transcoding workload over child processes in Node.js

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, scalability, child-process

I am transcoding a video from .mkv to MP4 format on a node.js server. When using a 10MB+ file the transcoding takes a whole lot of time. Is there a way to distribute the transcoding of a single file over multiple CPU cores by using the Node cluster and/or child_process modules?

Please see the project here:
https://github.com/wassbeer/video-transcoding-nodejs-ffmpeg

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your node.js server is not doing the transcoding. The `ffmpeg` installed on your OS is.

So using `cluster` in node won't help at all.

You can use `-threads` flag in `ffmpeg` to use multiple cores.

Comment: If your server happens to have a capable graphics card, you can also use NVENC to speed up the encoding part of the process significantly. Though the resulting MP4s tend to have a somewhat larger size for the quality. https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro